# Return results to SearchableActivity in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-search

**Situation**
As the topic suggest, I am working on an simple app, simple enough to be just a few fragments. The app is simple me querying items from an online server. 
However, in the app I would like to implement a search.

**Problem**

Although i'm a little experienced in searching I cannot seem to get it working in my fragment. When I click the "Search" a blank screen comes up, absent results.

**What I have done so far**

So far I have wrote what my search and volley which I have reason to believe is fine. Also in

> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

the onCreateView is grey, signifying that it isnt being called or used anywhere. Breakpoints placed also arent activated. Making be believe I never get to that activity.
Thank you

```
public class MySearchableActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    List<NumberResults> storiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recycle;


    private Toolbar toolbar;
    final Context context = this;

    //  @Override
    //protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.fragment_numbers);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
        Log.i(TAG, "in MySearchableActivity");


        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_numbers, container, false);
        recycle = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawrList);
        recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        handleIntent(intent);

        return layout;
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // get the query out of the intent
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String searchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doSearchQuery(searchQuery);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "in onNewIntent");
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void doSearchQuery(String query) { 

        final NumAdapters rvAdapter = new NumAdapters(storiesList);
        recycle.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://webserver.com/searchablewho.php?owner=" + query;


        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        storiesList.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            NumberResults stories = new NumberResults();

                            if (!jsonObject.isNull("number")) {
                                stories.name = jsonObject.getString("number");
                            }
                            if (!jsonObject.isNull("owner")) {


                                stories.age = jsonObject.getString("owner");




                            }
                            storiesList.add(i, stories);
                        }
                        rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // do something
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending ActionBarActivity instead of Fragment. That is why the method onCreateView is never called.